# Microsoft Access: Text Importing as Time

Tags: csv, ms-access, import

I have an Access 2007 database of call center statistics that I maintain for work. I receive the raw data from our IT department in a CSV file, which I then import into the database into tables organized by year. All of the header information for the table columns are included in the CSV files, so I simply import the first month into a new table, then append the other months to this table as they come along.

This has worked fine for years, but suddenly one of the fields has started importing improperly. There's a field called "Duration", which is a string in the format of xx:xx:xx. When I create the table I specify that it is a text field, and January displays all of its data properly.

However, whenever I append data to it, the additional Duration fields get converted to a Time field (i.e. 00:01:36 -> 12:01:36 AM). The field is still a text field, and the field displays properly in the import wizard, but all new data gets converted to Time.

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. When importing the file (.csv) I simply removed the time delimiter by clicking "Advanced" for the delimiter indications. It's strange to me that it didn't delimit it in the other tables, but for the most recent ones did. Nonetheless this solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a problem.  Open your table, select the design view and check what the Format property is.  If there is nothing there, enter your desired format.  That should display the data in the manner you desire.

Comment: This seems to just add additional characters in. So if I list @@:@@:@@ as the format the duration gets listed as '12:00:3:6 :AM'. Thanks for the help though--I know it's kind of a basic and "noob" question, but it's just been a while since I used access.

Comment: I created a couple of csv files and did an import and then an  append.  I was not able to reproduce the problem.  I only have Access 2010 if that makes a difference.